# How to load an HTML in Play without using a Controller class?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a web application that runs on Play framework. What I'm looking for is that given a link such as `<a href="test">Click me</a>` in a page loaded by Play, when the user clicks on the link I **don't** want to define a controller that will return `Ok(views.html.test())` to load the page pointed by `test`, I just want to load the page without running any functionality behind the scenes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not.

The way that "Gajendra Naidu" describe use default assert controller behind the scene.

To realize that method you need to add to the "route" file default assert controller call endpoint:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Then put your `test.html` file in the `/public` project directory, only after this you will be able to access this file by the URL `http://localhost:9000/assets/test.html`

Answer (score 1):

yes, if that HTML page is static. In that case copy the HTML page into public folder and access it directly.

If that page is not static, you have to go through the Controller only.

Comment: I created a file `test.html` in public folder, when I try to access it with `http://localhost:9000/test.html` I get "Action not found", any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. put test.html under public/
2. change your code to

   ```
   <a href='@routes.Assets.versioned("test.html")'>Click me</a>
   ```